# Ho to loop through Dom with PHP and find data-id

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following issue. I want to read in an external HTML file. I only need the HTML Elements between the `body` Tag. For that I have created below PHP Code and it works. I now need to add one more functionality, when I loop through I need to check if the HTML Element got a `data-id` and if so, then I have to add a value to that node. The Value is saved in a PHP Array and the Key is the same as the `data-id`. Any hint how I could do that? I would think that it needs to go into the foreach (`$children` as `$child`) loop, is that right? And if so, how can I check for the data-id? Any hint would be highly appreciated.

```
 $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTMLFile("extracontent.html");

function DOMinnerHTML(DOMNode $element,$attr) 
{ 
  $innerHTML = ""; 
  $children  = $element->childNodes;

foreach ($children as $child) 
{
    $innerHTML .= $element->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
}

    return $innerHTML; 
}  


$oldDom = $doc->getElementsByTagName("body"); 

foreach ($oldDom as $element) 
{ 
   $newDom = DOMinnerHTML($element); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with first looking for all child nodes within `body` which have `data-id` attribute using xpath queries then appending to them or building an array:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$dox = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $dox->query('/html/body//*[@data-id]');
$array = [];
foreach ($nodes as $key => $node) {
    $node->appendChild(new DOMText('add text'));
    $array[$key] = ['data-id' => 'add text'];
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Very interesting solution. Thank you very much. I am still trying to figure out each part and what it does. Silly question, but how would I find the value of data-id since this value is the matching key in my PHP Array and that is what I need for appendChild if I see it right...

Comment: If you need to append something to it above snippet works as is but if you want to store its value you have access to it through `textContent` property: `$node->textContent`

Comment: I actually have to find out the data-id. So for example I have a <h1 data-id="maintitle"></h1> I now need to know that this $node got the data-id maintitle so that I can match it with the value of my PHP Array. $node->textContent does not seem to give me this information or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Ahh sorry, I got it now. Simply use `getAttribute('data-id')`: `$node->getAttribute('data-id')`

Comment: Excellent it all seems to work. Thank you so much for your help !!